# Adding OnChange event to dynamically created vba form controls

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, combobox, listbox

I have a form in excel, where I need to have dynamically created Comboboxes and Listboxes. So, the idea is, each listbox is linked to combobox. The first ones are set up by default, and user can press the "Add" button, if he needs to add another combo + list boxes. So the code for "Add" button is following:

```
Private Sub AddCountry_Click()
aaa = "a"
Set comb = Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "CountryList" & Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + 1)
With comb
.Top = CountryList1.Top
.Width = CountryList1.Width
.Height = CountryList1.Height
.Left = (CountryList1.Width + 3) * Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + CountryList1.Left
.AddItem ("--Choose country--")
For i = 3 To 20
.AddItem Worksheets("Countries").Range("B" & i).Value
Next i
.Text = "--Choose country--"
End With

Set listb = Controls.Add("Forms.Listbox.1", "Countries" & Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + 1)
With listb
.Top = Countries1.Top
.Width = Countries1.Width
.Height = Countries1.Height
.Left = (Countries1.Width + 3) * Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + Countries1.Left
.ColumnCount = 2
.MultiSelect = 1
End With
CountryLabel.Caption = Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + 1
End Sub
```

The idea is, that Comboboxes must will have names "CountryList" and a number, that is stored in invisible label (to which is added +1 every time the button is bressed), so it will be CountryList1, CountryList2, etc. Same for listboxes.

So the thing is, that comboboxes are made and values (country names) are added correctly. But I did not get, how to use them after it? The thing, that I need is to - when a combobox is changed (user selects different country), the list box below must be filled with certain values (different for each country).

I assume, the problem might be in defining the name for combo/list box. So is it possible to add dynamical names (CountryList1, CountryList2, etc) and then somehow add OnChange Events? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to have a Class module, with `ListBox Events`, and `ComboBox Events`

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409871/dynamic-created-user-form-with-2-dependent-combo-boxes/44410821#44410821 - I did solve it here. You need an extra Class as @ShaiRado already said. You're after something like the cComboBox class I put there.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for the ComboBox. You can base the listbox of of it, since the principle is the exact same.

First create a class named cComboBox and put this code in there:

```
Private WithEvents p_ComboBoxEvents As MSForms.ComboBox
Private Sub p_ComboBoxEvents_Change()
    'Here you can handle the events.
End Sub
Public Property Let Box(value As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set p_ComboBoxEvents = value
End Property
Public Property Get Box() As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set Box= p_ComboBoxEvents
End Property
```

Next, in your existing code, you can add this cComboBox and just put the Combobox you're adding already:

```
'Add the custom box!
Private customBox as cComboBox
Private Sub AddCountry_Click()
    aaa = "a"
    Set comb = Controls.Add("Forms.Combobox.1", "CountryList" & Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + 1)

    With comb
        .Top = CountryList1.Top
        .Width = CountryList1.Width
        .Height = CountryList1.Height
        .Left = (CountryList1.Width + 3) * Val(CountryLabel.Caption) + CountryList1.Left
        .AddItem ("--Choose country--")
        For i = 3 To 20
            .AddItem Worksheets("Countries").Range("B" & i).Value
        Next i
        .Text = "--Choose country--"
    End With

Set customBox = New cComboBox
customBox.Box = comb

End Sub
```

Of course you might want to create an array of these so you can have as many as you want, regardless of how they're named. However: you'll see that if you change the added ComboBox value the `p_ComboBoxEvents_Change` will trigger.

Comment: ? Needs `Set` not `Let` on your class property and `Set` in the last line of the Sub.

Comment: In VBA you write the set property with the Let keyword. Since the Let part already does the set you don't need to use Set when setting this property. Go ahead, test it.

Comment: Huh, I never did it that way, but as you say it works just fine.  Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: You could give the class a public variable box of type ComboBox. Then you'd use 'set class.box = comb' indeed. However keeping it private like this is better practice and provides a clearer interface. Also it allows you to raise events in the setter if you need to.